# Method to filter out objective statements (or say facts)

Tags: classification, data-cleaning

I have millions of lines of statements containing both subjective (like I prefer the red skirt) and objective (Washington was born on February 22, 1732) statements or opinions. How can I separate them? Not manually.

By "objective", I mean if the object or predicative of the sentence changed, it would be in conflict with the truth. For illustration, in "She prefer red skirt.", if we change "red" or "skirt", the (new) statement would remain right, which can not apply to statements like "Washington was born on February 22, 2016".

The statements which should be pushed out:

1. Washington was born on February 22, 1732
2. Washington was born on February 21, 1731
3. Obama was born on February 22, 1732
4. Nobody A was born on February 22, 2016
5. Red is blue
6. Color is a day
7. I'm a robot
8. You are a person

Statements which should be kept:

1. I like coffee
2. Red is my favorite color
3. I hate him
4. You are awesome
5. You are clever
6. I was born years ago
7. You are very old
8. Tomorrow will be better

Comment: Please give lots more examples of what you would label subjective and objective. Can we get away with just looking at the main verb, e.g. 'think/feel/believe/prefer/...' or noun/adverb 'in my opinion/preference/belief'? Show us ones that fail a simple keyword filter like that.

Comment: You're right. The head word is important. It might be tackled by extracting the head word or all verbs in the sentence and then classify it using a discriminative model, for instance logistic regression or SVM.

Comment: Nouns or other words may also be relevant.

Comment: We still need lots more examples of what you would label subjective and objective, and you suggest below you might add a third class: neutral.

Comment: @smci I have updated my question.

Comment: I still don't see how it's well-defined. "She likes red" and "She likes purple" are not mutually exclusive. You can have multiple favorites, even.

Comment: Yes, I mean "She likes purple" and "She likes red" and "He likes red" are all treated as the same (pattern) but not for "Washington was born on February 22, 1732" and "Obama was born on February 22, 1732" and "Washington was born on February 22, 2016". I should make sure the output(at least alone) of the generative model is always right, meaning not being in conflict with facts only.

Comment: And "red is blue" or "color is a day" are all wrong.

Comment: @Lerner: Your categorisation still seems based on your own feeling of what differentiates a "fact" from a subjective statement. Now, that could be trained in a language model (and might be interesting), but you would need a lot of data. Also, I think the term "fact" is very hard to define linguistically, I don't think you will find a strong logical model, it is going to be fuzzy classification. That will also make it hard to collect data according to your goals from other people, as I for example might classify your sentences differently.

Comment: You'll never get an answer on an "objective" classification of objective vs. subjective.  If you still want to answer, perhaps you can add details of how such a model will be used, and then the right binary classification can be decided then.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an "objective" statement.

In your example: what if he wasn't born that day? Same statement, but is it still objective?

You may assume that "1 + 1 = 2" is an objective statement. But what if I'm doing binary math, and 1+1=0 then? So even that is subjective.

How would a machine tell apart these things, where philosophers will disagree with each other?

All you can do is provide training data examples of "your" (*subjective*) idea of objectiveness.

Comment: It doesn't matter either the statement is wrong or right. I should avoid a QA system providing any question with an absolute answer which increases error rate using the generative NN system.

Comment: A better counter example would be "she prefers the red skirt" Is this an objective or subjective statement?

Comment: I would say it can be viewed as a subjective statement since "prefers" indicates a feeling(which would be changing and not fixed).

Comment: Maybe it would be seemed as a neutral one?

Comment: Objectively neutral, or subjectively? :-) "She is hungry." Objective? Subjective? As you can see, **we don't agree on what is objective** - so the term "objective" is subjective...

Comment: @Lerner, you mean now make it three classes: Objective, Neutral and Subjective? You still haven't properly defined what each means.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some sentiment datasets when I encountered a so-called [subjectivity analysis](https://paperswithcode.com/task/subjectivity-analysis) on this [page](http://nlpprogress.com/english/sentiment_analysis.html). I thought what I meant can be found in this [paper](https://sentic.net/subjectivity-detection.pdf).